# Is there a well-defined pattern for binding controls to asynchronous data?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, asynchronous

Can you tell whether the following snippets are correctly binding to an asynchronous data source ?

While it *seems* to be working, i.e : UI does not freeze, I'm not entirely sure about the correctness as the MSDN documentation does not really talk about binding to 'async' methods in these docs :

[Binding.IsAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync.aspx)

[ObjectDataProvider.IsAsynchronous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.isasynchronous.aspx)

```
<pages:HottestPageProxy x:Key="PageProxy" ></pages:HottestPageProxy>

<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="DataProviderArtists" IsAsynchronous="True"  ObjectInstance="{StaticResource PageProxy}"  MethodName="GetArtists">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <system:String>Grabbing artists !</system:String>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

(HottestPageProxy object is a small helper that provides data for the controls)

```
public class HottestPageProxy
{
    [UsedImplicitly]
    public async Task<ArtistsQuery> GetArtists([CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(memberName);
        string apiKey = App.GetApiKey();
        Task<ArtistsQuery> topHottt = Queries.ArtistTopHottt(new ArtistTopHotttParameters
        {
            ApiKey = apiKey,
            Results = 100,
            Buckets = new[] {ArtistTopHotttBuckets.Hotttnesss}
        });
        return (await topHottt);
    }
}
```

**EDIT** : method that 'await topHottt' calls

```
public static async Task<ArtistsQuery> ArtistTopHottt(ArtistTopHotttParameters parameters)
{
    if (parameters == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("parameters");
    return await Get<ArtistsQuery>(parameters);
}

private static async Task<T> Get<T>(Parameters parameters) where T : Query
{
    if (parameters == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("parameters");
    ValidateParameters(parameters);

    string url = parameters.GetQueryUrl();
    var value = new Uri(url);
    using (var client = GetHttpClient())
    using (var message = await client.GetAsync(url))
    {
        // fetch message content (removed)
        return GetQueryResultObject<T>(s);
    }
}

private static T GetQueryResultObject<T>(string json) where T : class
{
    // create T from Json string (removed)
    return t;
}
```

**EDIT using AsyncEx**

Using your library works though the syntax now is :

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControlTopHott"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ... Path=Artists.Result.Artists ...}">
</ItemsControl>
```

Is 'Artists.Result.Artists' really what you expect me to use ? :)

The new syntax makes it more confusing as the source is :

```
public sealed class ArtistsQuery : Query
{
    public List<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
}
```

Not a big deal but if I could avoid such syntax that'd be great.

You said that .Result might bring a deadlock, did I miss something in implementing your solution then ?

Artists.PropertyChanged event raised the following messages :

- Status: RanToCompletion
- IsCompleted: True
- IsSuccessfullyCompleted: True
- Result: Success

I'll give a try to .ConfigureAwait(false) as you've mentioned in your post to see how it goes with it.

Forgot to mention, actually my implementation using .Result indeed **does not** block the UI as the typical time to get the result is a few seconds; I'd have seen the UI freeze. It seems right ... but I'm not certain whether it's correct, hence my question.

Comment: Doesn't `await topHottt` make it a synchronous call under the hood?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : not sure what you mean, I guess not as it returns right away. I've updated my question with the method it calls for reference.

Comment: `IsAsync` tells WPF to move the evaluation of the binding off the UI thread. It doesn't really have anything to do with C# `async`.

Comment: Right I've seen that on the doc., therefore my question as it's unclear whether it is aware/plays well with async/await. EDIT : I've tried to remove 'await', result is the same though Binding.Path now has a weird syntax : Result.Result.Artists.

Comment: @mikez : Forget my previous edit : when I've removed 'await' which in turn removed the need of 'async', it stopped working as soon as I removed 'async'.

Comment: @Aybe explain "stopped working". Did the data never appear? Did the data appear but the UI was unresponsive? Something else? If the data never appeared, were there any binding errors?

Comment: The data never appeared and it returned right away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have noted, the "asynchronous" members in WPF types have nothing to do with `async` and `await`.

You do have a problem in your binding; your path is using `Task.Result`, which will block the UI thread until the query is complete. Also, [using `Result` brings up the possibility of a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I describe on my blog.

I have another blog entry that deals with [`async` properties](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html), in particular how to data-bind to properties that are (logically) asynchronous. My [AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) has a [type called `NotifyTaskCompletion`](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NotifyTaskCompletion) that allows you to data-bind more naturally to an asynchronous `Task`.

So, e.g., you could do something like this:

```
public class HottestPageProxy
{
  public HottestPageProxy()
  {
    Artists = NotifyTaskCompletion.Create(GetArtists());
  }

  public INotifyTaskCompletion<ArtistsQuery> Artists { get; private set; }

  private Task<ArtistsQuery> GetArtists()
  {
    string apiKey = App.GetApiKey();
    return Queries.ArtistTopHottt(new ArtistTopHotttParameters
    {
        ApiKey = apiKey,
        Results = 100,
        Buckets = new[] {ArtistTopHotttBuckets.Hotttnesss}
    });
  }
}
```

Then you can data-bind to several different properties on `INotifyTaskCompletion<T>`, including `IsCompleted`, `ErrorMessage`, and `Result` (which does *not* block; it will return `default(T)` if the task is not completed).

Comment: I just gave it a try and updated my post with the results I got.

Comment: `Task.Result` can cause a deadlock; `INotifyTaskCompletion<T>.Result` will not. As far as the path goes, you can change it by modifying how your classes are structured. E.g., if you use `INotifyTaskCompletion<List<Artists>>`, then you can just databind to `Artists.Result`.

Comment: Oh right, haven't even thought about that. Thanks for your help !